# How to get Tasker CPU options available on MT4GS?

Tags: permissions, tasker

myTouch 4G Slide [MT4GS/Doubleshot]
ICS Virtous Inquisition ROM

I cannot get the tasker CPU options available.  I've checked the common problems listed at http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/cpu.html.  I can confrim that I have Superuser.apk installed in /system/app and that su binary is available.   I also have Secure Settings and Secure Setting Helper installed.  The frequencies are available and listed in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies but still no CPU option.  What do I need to do to figure out what is still wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what did it but it must be OS dependent as once I installed CyanogenMod9 Alpha6 I had those options available under performance settings and they also became available in the tasker menus as well.